# Is it possible to call the constructor of a class that inherits Enum without arguments?

Tags: python, class, enums, constructor, python-3.4

I have multiple classes, some inherit Enum, others don't and all of them end up mixed in big arrays such as show below:

```
from enum import Enum

class TestEnum(Enum):
    VAL_A = 0
    VAL_B = 1

class TestNotEnum():
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 1
```

As I wish to have a code as simple as possible for others to use, I would like to call the constructors of all the classes the same way to avoid as much confusion as possible.

This is how I would like to initialize them :

```
classes = [TestEnum(), TestNotEnum()]
```

The `TestNotEnum` class has no issues with it but the `TestEnum` throws the following exception : `TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'`. This is due to my (bad) use of Enum.

What can I do in order to have the `TestEnum` class still inherit Enum and yet have a constructor that has no arguments ?

I tried the following ( and a few similar tweaks ):

```
class TestEnum(Enum):
    VAL_A = 0
    VAL_B = 1
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestEnum, self).__init__()
```

but I only end up with different errors such as `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of the `classes` list? How do you intend to use its members? The [`Planet`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/enum.html#planet) example in the documentation shows you how you can define an `__init__()` on an `Enum` subclass, but I'm not sure exactly what you want it to do.

Comment: in the API I am using, the classes encapsulate bits ( 0's and 1's ) that are communicated to an other machine. The order of the content of the classes array allows the program to know how to interpret the bits. This also allows to easily adapt the program should the protocol change ( as the user would only have to swap the order of the classes / add one / remove one )

Comment: Ok, this sounds like it's a bit over my head, but the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/enum.html#enum-members-aka-instances) seems to state that Enum subclasses are designed to never be explicitly instantiated.

Comment: ah dang it you are right, your link gives the answer : it is not possible as Enums are all Singletons. Thanks for the answer ^^.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@glibdud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/789671/glibdud) who commented my question => it is not possible as show [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/enum.html#enum-members-aka-instances) : all Enum classes are Singletons and therefor I cannot call the construction the way I wished to do.

The other given solutions are interesting but did not fit my needs ( aenum adds new constraints and factory functions add a new layer of complexity for the API user )

An other possibility would have been to make my own Enum class that fit my needs but I chose to redo my architecture instead as it was faster : instead of putting class instances this way `classes = [TestEnum(), TestNotEnum()]`, I placed the references `classes = [TestEnum, TestNotEnum]` as a template array and the wished values in a second array of same size.

Not as good as a solution I would have liked but it works and allows the API user to do minimal work as he doesn't edit the template arrays.

Answer (score 2):

One option you have is to make factory functions named like your enums:

```
from enum import Enum

class TestEnum(Enum):
    VAL_A = 0
    VAL_B = 1

def TestEnum1():
    return TestEnum

class TestNotEnum():
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 1


instances = [TestEnum1(), TestNotEnum()]
print(instances)
```

Output:

```
[<enum 'TestEnum'>, <__main__.TestNotEnum object at 0x03648E30>]
```

Comment: It's an elegant solution - thank you - but I still end up with a documentation that needs to explain that some classes cannot be called directly.
Should nothing better be found I will use it

Comment: Well, Enums are Singletons ( thanks @glibdud for the information ) and therefor, I cannot instantiate the class as I would like to

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as this isn't possible with python's built-in enum class, a potential workaround is to use the advanced enum package. Simply replace `from enum import Enum` with `from aenum import enum as Enum` and your existing code works fine.

```
from aenum import enum as Enum
class TestEnum(Enum):
    VAL_A = 0
    VAL_B = 1
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestEnum, self).__init__()
class TestNotEnum():
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 1
classes = [TestEnum(), TestNotEnum()]
```

Comment: Note that I did `from aenum import enum as Enum` as your current code was already using a capital E for enums - if you wanted to just do `from aenum import enum`, and changed the capitalization in the rest of your code accordingly, you wouldn't need that part.

Comment: I saw that thanks. Is it possible to iterate over the attributes ?

Comment: The lower-case `enum` is not the `Enum` type -- it can't be `list()`ed, it lacks the improved `repr()`, and it won't interact properly with actual `Enum`'s.